# IFrame HTML5 keyboard focus,

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm making a game in HTML5 canvas, and I need it to be multiplayer so I am using node.js to accomplish this. But since my website is run a different server I have had to find a way to load the app on a page, on that server, I have used HTML IFrame to do that, which works fine and looks good except it doesn't get keyboard focus.

Is there a simple js script I can run to give it focus, either on the front end og inside the iframe?

```
<iframe src="mysite.com" height=750 width=1000 frameborder = 0 scrolling = "no" name="myFrame">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

I have seen there is a Jquery solution, but I hopped I could get around it, since the simple HTML is working well.

Comment: jsfiddle and tell me what are you trying to achieve from iframe

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same as if my canvas was on the main website and not inside an iframe. Which means all events from the keyboard and mouse can be used by the website inside the iframe, right now only the mouse events work.
I'm not really sure what you mean with jsfiddle tried to google it but can't see the connection.